# Expected value and covariance of compound Poisson process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, expectation, covariance

$Y_1,Y_2,...$ are independent random variables with a distribution identical to that of $Y$. $N(t)$ is a poisson process with parameter $\lambda$.

$$X(t)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N(t)}Y_n$$

Find the expected value $\mu_X(t)$ and the covariance $K_X(t,t')$. Is $X(t)$ stationary?

For the expected value I've found the following:

$\mu_X(t)=E[X(t)]=E[E[X(t)\mid N]]$

since $E[X(t)\mid N]=E[\sum\limits_{n=1}^N Y_n]=N\mu_Y$,

$E[E[X(t)\mid N]]=E[N\mu_Y]=t\lambda\mu_Y=\mu_X(t)$

But I'm stuck with the covariance $K_X(t,t')$. I tried this:
$K_X(t,t')=E[X(t)X(t')]-\mu_X(t)\mu_X(t')$ and I suppose I would also have to find $E[X(t)X(t')]$ by computing $E[E[X(t)X(t')\mid N,N']]$.

Then $E[X(t)X(t')\mid N,N']=E\left[\sum\limits_{n=1}^N Y_n \sum\limits_{{n'}=1}^{N'} Y_{n'}\right].$ But I can't seem to work this out. Any tips on this?

Comment: Do you know that the process $(X(t))_{t \geq 0}$ has independent increments?

Comment: I do, but I don't see how I could use independent increments to find that last expectation. @saz

Comment: Suppose that $t<t'$ and write $$\mathbb{E}(X(t) X(t')) = \mathbb{E}([X(t)-X(t')] X(t')) + \mathbb{E}(X(t')^2).$$ This leads to the conclusion that it suffices to calculate $\mathbb{E}(X(t)^2)$ (or, alternatively, $\text{var}(X(t))$).

Answer (score 2):

If $t\leqslant s$, then $N(t)\leqslant N(s)$ hence $$X(t)X(s)=\sum_{n,k}Y_nY_k\mathbf 1_{n\leqslant N(t),k\leqslant N(s)}=\sum_{n}Y_n^2\mathbf 1_{n\leqslant N(t)}+\sum_{n\ne k}Y_nY_k\mathbf 1_{n\leqslant N(t),k\leqslant N(s)},$$ which implies that $E(X(t)X(s))=E(Y^2)U+E(Y)^2(V-U)$ with $$U=\sum_{n}P(n\leqslant N(t))=E(N(t)),$$ and $$ V=\sum_{n,k}P(n\leqslant N(t),k\leqslant N(s))=E(N(t)N(s)).$$
The value of $E(N(t))$ should be known. On the other hand, using $N(s)=N(t)+(N(s)-N(t))$ where $N(s)-N(t)$ is independent of $N(t)$ and distributed as $N(s-t)$, one gets $$V=E(N(t)^2)+E(N(t))E(N(s-t)),$$ from which the value of $V$, hence of $E(X(t)X(s))$, should arise...

Comment: if t <= s then t-s <= 0 which would imply that N(t-s) doesn't exist unless t=s. If I follow your work correctly, it looks like you probably mean N(s-t)

Comment: @jodag Indeed. Good catch, corrected, thanks.